# Creating web application with Spring MVC and Maven in intellij

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm following a tutorial on spring. But i got a bit of stuck when i need to create an web application in intellij.

The steps i did :

Create new Maven project and use archetype `org.apache.maven.archetypes maven-archetype-webapp`

Then i download following dependency

```
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
```

At this point i get something like this

[image]

So i manually create some folders like this.

[image]

Is this an correct way to proceed ?
Should i improve something to this ?
One thing i also notice is there is no meta inf should i also create one manually ? Or is this no longer useful ?

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot it will be better if you generate your project using the [Spring Boot Starter tool](http://start.spring.io) and then import the project directly into IDEA.  Will save you a lot of time, get you a working application out-of-the-box and save you the hassle of figuring of dependency versions that will work together.

Comment: @manish, If i'm using spring boot i get even less folders ? Do i need to create them separately too? And why should i not use all the latest dependency versions instead?

Comment: The point of using the starter tool is to get a solution that is guaranteed to work.  The sample project generated by the tool uses the latest dependencies so you don't need to worry about that.  Once you have the sample project, you can add any folder structure to it that you want.